# Section Numbers with Recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm having trouble with an assignment, and probably one that's very familiar ([link](https://cse.sc.edu/~mgv/csci146/progs/prog5/hw.html)). It's problem 2 titled "section numbers".

Basically, it's a recursion problem that prints out a string along with a section number, defined by levels. If there's one level, it prints string1. to string9.
If there's two, string1.1. to string9.9., etc. The problem I'm having is the last detail, where the program prints out the original string by itself.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>  // Provides cin, cout
#include <cstdlib>   // Provides EXIT_SUCCESS
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void numbers(ostream& outs, const string& prefix, unsigned int levels);

int main()
{
    numbers(cout, "THERBLIG", 2);
}

void numbers(ostream& outs, const string& prefix, unsigned int levels)
{
     if(levels == 0)
    {
         cout << prefix << endl;
    }

     else
    {
         for(int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
        {
             string s = (prefix + char('0' + i));
             s += '.';

             numbers(outs, s, levels - 1);
        }
     }
}
```

I understand that prefix is being overwritten through the recursion, so instead of the original string being printed it's string1.1. What I don't know is how to keep the original intact so that it can be printed at the end.
(I know there's already a post here with the exact same question, but I've already tried both solutions and I wasn't able to get anywhere.)

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: If you want the original prefix to be printed after the recursion ends why not print it after calling the recursive method.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use static local variables, or append using recursion.

If you're ever stuck with recursion, try use recursion for calculating factorials ( the classic example ). Most uses derrive from this.

Also, please don't post your homework here.